# Uniform Convergence of $f_n(x)=1+\cos(x/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

How to see that the series of functions $f_n(x)=1+\cos(x/n)$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

To prove $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly to $1$ is easy. Let $x=0$, then $|f_n(0)-1| = 1 > 1/2$.

But how to prove $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly to any function $f$?

Comment: Check the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence: given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $x$ and for all $n,m\geq N$, $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon$. (Or in this case, check that it fails.)

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about Cauchy criterion. But I'm not sure how to check that it fails.

Comment: The important term is the cosine - abuse its periodicity! Draw pictures to see what's going on. One idea: Take $n$ an integer and consider $x = 2\pi n$. What's $f_n(x)$? $f_{2n}(x)$? Can you turn this into a proof by contradiction?

Comment: So I can let $m=2n$, then $|f_n(2n\pi)-f_{2n}(2n\pi)|=2$. Done.

Comment: Yes, now technically you'll have to put everything into a formal $\varepsilon$-$N$ proof, but hopefully this is the easy part for you!